# How to mock individual methods of a SpyBean?

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, spy

I'm working on a test class where one specific test needs the actual implementation of a method of a service class that I'm mocking. So I thought, why not use `@SpyBean` instead of `@MockBean` and use the actual implementation where I need it (don't have to do anything) and use a mocked implementation where I need it (need to write a one-liner to setup the mocked method).

I've found [this great and quite detailed blog post](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/20/using-spring-boot-spybean/), that explains how to achieve this, section "@SpyBean to the rescue".

The only problem is that it doesn't work, the real implementation is used and those tests succeed, but the mocked methods don't kick in. I'm using Mockito 2.21.0 and Spring Framework 5.1.0. Now I'm using separate test classes for that purpose, but I'd like to figure out how to do this the right way.

I'm pretty much doing exactly the same thing as in the example on this blog:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestclassAA.class)
class TestclassAA {
@SpyBean
private XXService xxService;

private ClassUsingXXService testee;

@Test
void test1 {
   // ..
   // use mocked implementation of save() -> does not work, real method called
   doReturn(new XXRequestModel()).when(xxService).save(any(XXModel.class));
   var result = testee.doSomething();
   //.. 
}

@Test
void test2 {
  // ..
  // use actual implementation of save() -> works, real method called
  var result = testee.doSomething();
  //.. 
}
```

Basically I'm getting errors messages that hint that what I'm doing isn't possible at all with a spy:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();

Hints:
1. missing thenReturn()
2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

Anybody any idea how to do this?

Comment: what is your code, what exactly do you want to achieve (in code), what method should be called?

Comment: I have let's say two tests in the same test class, I want a SpyBean that calls a mocked method when I say so, otherwise not. See the updated post for details

Comment: Is this your full testclass? I would at least expect an `@RunWith` annotation...

Comment: This is of course a stripped down version for simplicity. The class has verything it needs. I have everything running, just the setup of a mocked method on a spybean fails. But I'll ammedn the posted code a bit